# How to insert a method into a future method in dart?

Tags: dart

I have a method of type Future when I call other methods in this method it does not recognize them.

Here is my code:

```
      static Future<void> createUser(String email, String password, String role,
      {GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey}) async {
       RestClient.getAuthToken().then((String token) {
      Map<String, dynamic> postData = {
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "role": role
     };

    RestClient.procesPostRequest("user/add", postData, token)
      .then((Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    //String message;
    if (data.containsKey('error')) {
      // print('Error Data : $data');
      // message = WSErrorHandler.fromJson(data).getMessage();
      isNotRegisteredState();
      //return Future.value(message);
    } else {
      isRegisteredState();
    }
    });
    }).catchError((onError) {
   print('$onError');
   return Future.value('error');
  });
 }
```

These are the methods I call inside the future method:

```
     void isRegisteredState() {
      _isRegistered = true;
      notifyListeners();
     }

    void isNotRegisteredState() {
    _isRegistered = false;
    notifyListeners();
    }
```

And this is the error I get when I run the program:

`Error: Method not found: 'isNotRegisteredState'`, `Error: Method not found: 'isRegisteredState'`

Comment: Where are `isRegisteredState` and `isNotRegisteredState` defined?  As long as they are in scope where you create the callback you pass to `.then()`, they should work.  It's hard to tell with the limited code you've posted.  If `isRegisteredState`/`isNotRegisteredState` are *instance* methods, you would need to invoke them on an object instance since `createUser` is `static` and has no `this` object.

Comment: the both methods and the createUser method are defined in the same class

Comment: As I pointed out, `isRegisteredState`/`isNotRegisteredState` are *instance* methods but `createUser` is a *static* method.  Either `isRegisteredState` (and `_isRegistered`, and `notifyListeners`) also needs to be `static`, or you need to create an *instance* of your class and invoke `isRegisteredState` on that.

Comment: In other words, your question has nothing to do with `Future`s.  You'd have the same problem if you had: `static void createUser() { isRegisteredState(); }`.

Comment: i remove the static keyword and defined an object on which i call it and it  works